# Approval flow for only one out of two gateways

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are running WSO2 API Manager 4.1 with two gateways (internal and external). We would like to setup approvals for deploying to the external gateway, but not the internal gateway.

Is there a way of distinguishing on gateway, and only set up approvals for deployments to the one gateway?

We have only found a way of setting up approvals for deploying to any gateway.

Comment: Can you elaborate `We have only found a way of setting up approvals for deploying to any gateway.`. How did you set this up?

Comment: Are you referring to the API State Change workflow?

Comment: Yes, what we have tried is the API State Change Approval Workflow